# Extract text from PDF(I have link to PDF) in ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf

I have a link like

```
      http://www.downloads.com/help.pdf
```

I want to download this, and parse it to get the text content.

How do I go about this? I also plan to tag-ize(if there is a word like that) the extracted text

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either use the pdf-reader gem (the example/text.rb example is simple and worked for me): https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader

Or the command-line utility pdftotext.

Comment: Is there like a good tutorial kind of thing on it? I'm new to ruby but just copying example code feels bad for me

Comment: I wouldn't say adapting their example is a bad thing. Here is a tutorial though that may interest you and explains the concepts a bit: http://pullmonkey.com/2010/01/18/ruby-pdf-reader-gem-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

The [Yomu gem](https://github.com/Erol/yomu) will also be able to extract the text from a PDF (as well as other MIME types) for you.

```
require 'yomu'
Yomu.new(file_path).text
```

Comment: I've tried a few gems and found this most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [DocRipper](https://github.com/pzaich/doc_ripper), a gem I maintain, that provides a Ruby interface for text extraction from a number of document formats including PDF, doc, docx and sketch.

DocRipper uses pdftotext under the hood and avoids Java dependencies.

```
require 'doc_ripper'

DocRipper::rip('/path/to/file.pdf') => "Pdf text"
```

You can read remote files using the Ruby standard library:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'doc_ripper'

tmp_file = open("some_uri")
DocRipper::rip(tmp_file.path)
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please let us know the syntax for using docripper with link to file path rather than local file path?

Comment: @Sagar Are you referring to a remote file path?

Comment: yes!!! I am using amazon s3 storage so I will be having only the links to the files.

Comment: @Sagar I've added an example of how you might interact with a remote path. You'll need to write the file to disk in some manner so that DocRipper can scrape the document.